# Polymorphic type aliases in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, alias

Short version: I want to alias a type of functions `type myType = [Int] -> (Tree Int,[Int])` but polymorphically (meaning I can put in anything instead of just `Int`s). How could I do this?

Long version: I currently have:

```
data Colour = R | B deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
data Tree elt = E | T Colour (Tree elt) elt (Tree elt) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

type Set a = Tree a
```

I'd like to have:

```
type Funcs = [elt] -> (Tree elt, [elt])
```

and then write some functions that will have the type `Funcs`

```
treeify_zero :: Treeify_t
treeify_zero lst = (E,lst)

treeify_one :: Treeify_t
treeify_one (h:t) = ((T R E h E), t)
```

Like this. Currently, I can't get `type Funcs = forall elt. [elt] -> (Tree elt, [elt])` to run properly in GHCi. and if I use `type Funcs elt = [elt] -> (Tree elt, [elt])` GHCi complains my definitions of `treeify_zero/one` "should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    In the type signature for `to': to :: Treeify_t"

Comment: Is it `Tree` or `Tre` ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: in my own source I named it `Tre` but thought it would be better to name it `Tree` when asking the question. I didn't change all the instances resulting in those typos. but now I've fixed them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to parameterize the type synonym -- `elt` can't just come out of nowhere. Maybe you're after

```
type Funcs elt = [elt] -> (Tree elt, [elt])
```

Alternatively you want some other binder, like `type Funcs = forall elt. [elt] -> (Tree elt, [elt])`. But you haven't said what you're trying to do, so it's hard to say. :-)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to implement an interesting algo that converts a list of anything (elt) into a set (with the specific implementation of ordered Red-Black trees) of that same anything and I'm not sure if it's matters if elt is a dependent type. What is the difference between your former and latter examples? in both we end up with a polymorphic type that is of functions that go from lists to (tree,list) right?

Comment: Also, I'm not understanding `type` in Haskell very well. I would have thought `type Funcs elt` means a type of functions that from `elt`s to a pair of an `elt` tree and an `elt` list.

What exactly does it mean?

Comment: @C.E.Sally `type Funcs elt = [elt] -> (Tree elt, [elt])` means anywhere you see `Funcs foo` in a type signature, you can replace it with `([foo] -> (Tree foo, [foo])`.

Comment: @C.E.Sally If you think of `Funcs elt` standing in for `(Tree elt, [elt])` then you can see the `elt` parameter in `Funcs elt` as "exposing" the internal type `elt`. This lets you use the information later, such as a function like `Funcs elt -> Tree elt`. If you bound it with `forall` as @shachaf suggests then `elt` won't "escape" and were you to try to write `Funcs -> Tree elt` it would be difficult since we can't be sure `Funcs` was internally using the same `elt` as `Tree` eventually gets.